# How to import data from elasticsearch to sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to import data from elasticsearch to sql server database, I have done import of data from sqlserver to elastic search using logstash, I reversed input and output but its throwing the error as shown in second screen:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't add images of text. Just copy and paste the text here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check the below.

input
{
    stdin { }
}
output {
    jdbc {
        driver_jar_path => '/opt/sqljdbc42.jar'
        connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=databasename;user=username;password=password"
        statement => [ "INSERT INTO log (host, timestamp, message) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", "host", "@timestamp", "message" ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully finished it. You can see my blog or the config.

blog:
[Output to SQL database by Logstash](https://datamansamxiao.wordpress.com/2019/12/25/logstash-data-output-to-sql-database/)

OK. now we need to install the “logstash" output JDBC plug-in. It’s very important if you don’t have the plug-in. Ya! You DO NOT need a “input" plug-in because it’s default set. But you need the output JDBC plug-in. It’s really important.

```
> bin\logstash-plugin.bat install logstash-output-jdbc
```

config:

```
input
{
elasticsearch {
hosts => [“localhost:9200″]
index => “yourindex"
}
}
output {
jdbc{
driver_jar_path => “C:\MSSQLJDBC\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
connection_string => “jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=databasename;user=username;password=userpassword"
statement => [ “INSERT into DB.TMP.samsamt (w, test1, test2, kkk) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", “client_num", “consignee_name", “@timestamp","host" ]
}
}
```

Operation

```
> bin\logstash.bat -f config\elk.conf
```

And the statement will be the transform design part. You need to mapping the columns you want in statement.

```
(w, test1, test2, kkk)
```

is the part of structured table column.

```
“client_num", “consignee_name", “@timestamp","host"
```

is the mapping column in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing in the log

> Couldn't find any output plugin named 'jdbc'.

It is available as a community plugin, though not sure it works with Logstash 7 (yet):

https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc

Comment: What I'm saying is that the `jdbc` plugin you're using is not an output plugin, but an input plugin, so you need to install the one I'm referring to instead.